Source for "Adam Wanted to Taste the Food"
Rav Dessler in Michtav m'Eliyahu 2 p146 & 149 quotes an unsourced chazal that Adam deep down "wanted to taste the food" (רצה לטעום התבשיל) ie tree of knowledge. Anyone know the source or something similar?
